# LED Monitor Turns Transparent RED

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card

When i turn on my computer for the first time. The monitor looks fine, but after 10 mins or so, the monitor turns a bit redish, but not completely red. This is my second replacement of monitor. Is there a problem in my graphics card? or in my VGA cable. My cable is very cheap, cost like $2.

windows 7
led 19" NOVA
running at 1024X768

Comment: Is it "redish" enough to indicate that the green channel dropped out completly on what your viewing?   Certannly test with a new cable item when it is an analog VGA cable.  The Vga sends out the signal in 3 seperate analog colors and a sync, If a few pins or wires are not working right , it could drop a whole of the 3 out.  If not it is more likely that it would show various interferance before any reduction (not loss) of the signals.

Comment: so, i need a new VGA cable?

Comment: I cannot be sure that is what is wrong, I would try a new cable.  Here I would also try a different monitor, but I do not know if you have access to another monitor.